# What section of memory are static local constants stored in?

Tags: c

I know global constant will be stored in "Read Only" section. But What section of memory are static local constants stored in?

Comment: You are wrong.  Global constants MAY be stored in a read-only section, but it's not a given.

Comment: What compiler and what output file format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the compiler and the platform you're compiling for. They may be placed on the bottom of the stack, in the data segment of the primary thread, or simply on the heap, or even somewhere else.