# Where are static constants stored?

Tags: c, static, constants, memory-layout

If a constant is defined globally, it goes to the `text` segment. Local constants get pushed onto the `stack`. Static variables get stored into either the `data` or the `bss` segment depending on if it is initialised in place and what it is initialised with.

What about `static const`? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285727/what-section-of-memory-are-static-local-constants-stored-in) links to another one which is only about static variables, not constants. I suppose static constants should be stored in the `text` segment as read-only variables, but I'm not sure. Where is it commonly stored?

Comment: What does the map file say?

Comment: @MartinJames I only have executable after compilation

Comment: Tell your linker to write a full map file...

Comment: @MartinJames what options are for that in `gcc` or `clang`?

Comment: Sorry....are you asking me to look up linker commands for you?

Comment: @MartinJames of course I thought you knew how to do that if you proposed that. Besides, I only compile via command prompt

Comment: Google the linker command-line directives.

Answer (score 2):

A `static const` may be folded at compile time. If it is not, then it is stored in the `data` or `bss` segment as though it were a `static` (but other modules can't link to it). Storing it in the `text` segment is valid, but very few compilers do so. I've only seen it in embedded compilers where the RAM/ROM distinction matters. Newer toolchains often have a `rodata` segment that takes static and global constants.

Comment: Well, my `clang` compiler stores it next to constants as if it was in the `text` section. `gcc` does the same, but this one does not seem to follow the standard memory layout (somewhy constants have higher addresses than initialised global variables)

Comment: @Kaiyakha: The higher address indicates to me it's using `rodata`.

Comment: @is it higher than `data`?

Comment: @Kaiyakha: Depends on link order, but it can be.

Comment: What about `clang`? The addresses of `static const` (local and global) are near the addresses of string literals and other global constants and all of the addresses are much less than the addresses of variables from `data` segment (global vars initialised in place with non-zero values)

Comment: @Kaiyakha: I don't use clang.

Comment: Well ok, what do you mean by `folded`?

Comment: @Kaiyakha: The compiler is allowed to place the value of a static const everywhere it is used and eliminate the variable.

Comment: Finally I think `static const` is near other constants for both `clang` and `gcc`. For `clang` it's more likely that it is in the `text` segment because its address is the least along with the other constants, and for `gcc` it is probably in what you call `rodata`. Anyway, it is always besides other constants for the both compilers.

Comment: Basing where you think something is placed based on address is a bit silly, take a look at an object dump and remove the doubt. (objdump on *nix platforms or dumpbin.exe if using MSVC). Although taking an address itself may force creation of an object that would not otherwise be needed.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir that's the point, I have neither *nix nor MSVC. I compile via command prompt on Windows

Comment: Your toolset produces a binary in _some_ format, very likely there is a tool that will dump the resulting object file, even if that is not a native format for the platform. For example, my cross-compile clang installations have llvm-objdump.